# How can I get the name of term post meta value which equals term id

Tags: query, terms, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom taxonomy (location) that is being populated automatically by an advanced custom field on user save. The issue is that it saves the term_id in the postmeta meta_value field. When I echo that field in my archive or taxonomy template it obviously shows me the term_id and not the actual term name (ex. I get 41, instead of California displaying). I have tried multiple things to get this to appear and days and basically any query I do ends up just a blank space displaying on my archive/taxonomy page. Can anyone assist me in how I might retrieve the term name from the term_id being outputted?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) to retrieve a term by its ID:

```
$term_id = 123;
$term = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, 'location' );
if( $term ){
    echo $term->name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just had to change the $term_id statement to make it variable `$queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;`